# SUPEE 6788 and Password Reset (blank page)

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I've installed SUPEE 6788. Then noticed that password reset page is blank when you click on the reset link in the email. Any ideas how to make the reset page to show up ?
Previously reset page use to be this
/customer/account/resetpassword/
After patch update it's
/customer/account/changeforgotten/ **and it's blank**

**Tech description from the Patch**

APPSEC-1027, Insufficient Protection of Password Reset Process

This change affects templates by adding form_key to customer registration page template/customer/form/register.phtml and similar changes to password forgotten page layout/customer.xml and template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml. If your store includes customized registration or password forgotten template, make sure to add this key there as well..

Comment: Did you check the php error log, exception.log and system.log?

Comment: never heard of changeforgotten. does it happen in the base theme?

Comment: Changeforgotten located in app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Changeforgotten.php

Comment: "reset link in the email" -- it's not clear what you mean by this, which makes answering this question difficult.

Comment: I have found a solutions, basically yoy need to a few lines in customer.xml  http://www.atwix.com/magento/security-patch-supee-6788-installation-issues/

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In case after the [SUPEE-6788 patch](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788) you experience «*Forgot password issue*», in other words the page is blank.

You have to edit `customer.xml` file and replace customer layout `customer_account_resetpassword` with `customer_account_changeforgotten`.

> File location: `app/design/frontend/theme/default/layout/customer.xml` the theme name might be different for you.

Refresh your cache, and all good!

Comment: Totally worked for me. Indeed it has changed the name of the page.

Comment: I also had to change the block type: `<block type="customer/account_resetpassword"` to `<block type="customer/account_changeforgotten"`

Comment: Good job, this answer should be accepted.
the `customer.xml` in the base-template actually is changed with the update, so this is only needed if you have a custom one.

Comment: there are multiple customer.xml - if you published the directory structure more people could get help  app/design/frontend/theme/default/layout/customer.xml

Comment: @Jon i've edited the answer to include the path for future use :)

Comment: Great this made my day ;)

Comment: Magento strikes again with pointless and site-breaking changes.

Answer (score 1):

Update your `app/design/frontend/%custom%/%theme%/layout/customer.xml` layout file with these changes:

[image]

*source: [gist.github.com/Nolwennig](https://gist.github.com/Nolwennig/fd659021c029c9293eb21d31a4796ddc/revisions#diff-75b9f7dbed114163728f3b96be32c1bd)*

Comment: ohhhhhhhh thanks, it would have take me a lot of time to find the origin of the problem!

Answer (score 1):

```
Find

<customer_account_resetpassword translate="label">
    <label>Reset a Password</label>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
            <title>Reset a Password</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
            <title>Reset a Password</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/account_resetpassword" name="resetPassword" template="customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</customer_account_resetpassword>

And Paste Below Code

<customer_account_changeforgotten translate="label">
    <label>Reset a Password</label>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
            <title>Reset a Password</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
            <title>Reset a Password</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/account_resetpassword" name="resetPassword" template="customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</customer_account_changeforgotten>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit customer.xml file and replace

`customer_account_resetpassword translate="label"` to `customer_account_changeforgotten translate="label"`

and `block type="customer/account_resetpassword"` to `block type="customer/account_changeforgotten"`

File location is `app/design/frontend/theme/default/layout/customer.xml`, the theme name might be different for you.