# Magento forgot password link doesn't parse / convert

Tags: php, magento

I'm busy fixing some webshops that suffered from the invalid **customer.xml** issue that came with the SUPEE 6788 security patch. I'm down to my last one, however, everything in my **customer.xml** is (probably) in the right place.

Whenever Magento sends me a mail with my password reset link and I click on it, I get a 404 error straight from the server (so not from within Magento). Normally, Magento parses the given URL (which is like this; `http://yoursite.com/customer/account/resetpassword/id=[id]&token=[token]` ) to `http://yoursite.com/customer/account/changeforgotten`.

Navigating manually to `account/changeforgotten` doesn't work because of the missing session token and user id, but it does return my form, which indicates my **customer.xml** is probably fine.

Does anybody know where Magento parses this URL, and how to fix it? Or is something else going on?

Some insight or advice would be great :)

**TIA**

(edit; this is the xml issue i'm talking about; [SUPEE 6788 and Password Reset (blank page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33443503/supee-6788-and-password-reset-blank-page))

Answer (score 1):

404 page - can you clarify if the 404 page is coming from magento or is it just a 404 with a white background ?

when you visit http://yoursite.com/customer/account/resetpassword.....

the request will goto app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php

```
public function resetPasswordAction()
```

You can try modifying this function to see if the request is coming here, and then debug further..
Note -
If you have any custom module installed for login, it should have possibly overiden the AccountController , then in this case you should try debugging the AccountController of that module

Comment: The 404 page has a white background, I already mentioned its from the server. Thanks for your input, I'll check out what this function does :)

Comment: oh sorry ,if its from server it could be a different problem...some module disabled, is the customer able to login and visit account dashboard ??

Comment: Ah no problem, yep, the user is able to login and visit the dashboard (seeing the latest orders etc.), it's just the reset password link that doesn't parse..

Comment: In that case please check if there is any module overiding AccountController and in that controller see if a function like resetPasswordAction() exists..