# Magento 1.9.0.1: Password reset after Patch

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I installed patch SUPEE 6788 and the password reset form was no longer working. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33443503/supee-6788-and-password-reset-blank-page) and by changing the customer.xml I could restore the reset functionality. The problem is: if the user enters a wrong password (ie the password must have a minimum length of 6, but the user enters only 4 letters), there is no error message. There is a

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml(); ?>
```

right before the form tag, but it still doesn't show the error message. Weirdly enough, if I navigate to the login form afterwards, the errormessages that should be displayed at the resetform are displayed there.

Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: can you share your site url?

Comment: I'm not sure if the customer would be comfortable with that, so unfortunately no

Comment: its ok, :)  check if there is a custom validation class added to the password field for the password length restriction

Comment: The classes for the password field are required-entry and validate-password