# Reset password link return blank page

Tags: magento, passwords, magento-1.9

Reset password link return blank page after I upgrade to the Magento 1.9.2.4

[image]

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33443503/supee-6788-and-password-reset-blank-page

Comment: also this : [link2](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107502/change-forgotten-password-page-blank) & [link3](http://www.tripleginteractive.com/blog/magento/magentos-forgot-reset-password-page-blank-fix/) for more information.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is related to SUPPEE-6788.
Either you upgraded Magento or install this Patches. So I suggest you to please add FORM KEY in forgot password form.

And if you didn't change it in customer.xml then please change reset password code from base to your theme's customer.xml

Comment: chat @ http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121528/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-nsdlfefinedieicbe

Comment: come to chat box pls

Comment: I have no sufficient reputation for it so please ask here. @JeevaRathinam

Comment: what can i do first

Comment: Add <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />

Comment: Add this code in forgot password form. after <form> tag start

Comment: where is forgot password form  ??

Comment: do u have skype id

Comment: yes 'mayurasisodia'

Comment: am send invition. pls accept

Comment: Solution :       https://magentary.com/kb/reset-password-blank-page-after-supee-6788/

Answer (score 1):

Change forgotten password page was changed with **SUPEE-6788** security patch.

In most cases all that's required to fix the issue is to copy `customer_account_changeforgotten` layout update handle from `base/layout/customer.xml` to `[theme]/layout/customer.xml`.

You can find more information on official patch documentation page: https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details

Best of luck!

Comment: could you pls join chat

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121528/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-nsdlfefinedieicbe

Comment: i couldn't get you

Comment: @JeevaRathinam: I'm there. :)